# mysql replace an empty value

Tags: mysql, replace

I was wondering if this is possible from mysql.

`SELECT username FROM users_table`

If username is NULL I would like to display something like "Unknown" I can do it on php comfortable with it just wondering if this something worth looking into :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT IFNULL(username, 'Unknown') FROM users_table
```

OR

```
SELECT COALESCE(username, 'Unknown') FROM users_table
```

Comment: nice one :) thnx m8 question, using this method instead of the php version which one do you think is faster?... its just a stupid question but worth knowing :)

Comment: Both should be identical, `IFNULL` are mysql specifically, while `COALESCE` is a common string function for other sql as well. (COALESCE might slightly slower as it accept multiple arguments), but  I think the difference is too small to mention

Comment: @Val If you use PHP you are able to handle blank users differently (e.g., assign a CSS class to display them in italics).

Comment: you can do it by adding username value on the class and just do the same `class="<?php echo $username=='unknown'?'italic':'normal'; ?>"`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IF` function.

```
IF(condition, if_true, if_false)
```

So, your query is:

```
SELECT IF(NULL(username), "Unknown", username) FROM users_table
```

Read more: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Did you mean `IF(ISNULL(...`? I can't seem to find a `NULL()` function in the reference...

Answer (score 1):

Last but not least, `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN username IS NULL THEN '(Unknown)'
        ELSE username 
    END AS username
FROM users_table
```

I like it because it's easy to generalise when you have complex expressions (you can add as many `WHEN` as you want) and it works in many DBMS.

*(In this case I'd use COALESCE from [@ajreal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603434/mysql-replace-an-empty-value/4603468#4603468).)*